# How to make a OptionMenu maintain the same width?

Tags: python, tkinter, optionmenu

I have a snippet which creates an `OptionMenu` widget.

```
...
options = ('White', 'Grey', 'Black', 'Red', 'Orange', 
           'Yellow', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Cyan', 'Purple')
var = StringVar()
optionmenu = OptionMenu(par, var, *options)
optionmenu.grid(column=column, row=row)
...
```

One problem I've encountered is every time a new option is selected, the width of the widget changes. I believe this is due to the text within the widget changing widths. How do I make the widget hold a consistent width?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you use the `grid` command to place the widget in its parent, have the widget fill its cell (try `sticky="ew"`)

Comment: This does not work for me. I am using a dropdown in a frame. Yet it expands it for long options in the dropdown.

Comment: An alternate could be to find the maximum width of all widgets in that column and then set the default of the variable within the option menu to be " "*(max_width/font_size_of_option_widget). The size of the widget can be obtained using widget.update() and then widget.winfo_width()

Answer (score 35):

To the best of my knowledge, you can use `optionmenu.config(width=<YOUR_WIDTH>)` as follows:

```
...
optionmenu = OptionMenu(par, var, *options)
optionmenu.config(width=<YOUR_WIDTH>)
optionmenu.grid(column=column, row=row)
...
```

Answer (score 3):

```
optionmenu.configure(width=<YOUR_WIDTH_HERE>)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the exact same boat as the OP was 12 years ago - placing dropdowns in a frame, only to discover that no solution exists for setting them to expand horizontally and fill that frame. As a result they're always resizing (and re-centering) any time a different-length option is selected. sticky='' has no effect whatsoever. width='' works, but now you're setting a fixed width that is only optimized for one resolution.

Of course the terrible solution is to use a monospace font and add spaces to the end of all the options in the dropdown. I just don't understand how there can be no real solution for this. These dropdowns look absolutely atrocious as a result.

Comment: i've posted an answer to this, in case you're looking for a better solution.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. Do you happen to have a link?

Comment: it's just below your response here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/76903139/4744864

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with

```py
frame.columnconfigure(1, minsize=120)
optmenu = ttk.OptionMenu(frame,...)
optmenu.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.EW)
```

Not optimal as you have to guess the pixel width of the colume, but it works.

Here are some links, I found to be useful in coming up with this answer.

https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-grid/

[Set minimum width of column in grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52844549/set-minimum-width-of-column-in-grid)

https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html