# Set minimum width of column in grid

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to set a minimum width to a column in a grid, but it is having no effect:

```
labelProjectId = Tkinter.Label(frame, text="Id", background='white', borderwidth=1, relief="solid")
abelProjectId.grid(row=row, column=0, sticky=("W", "E"))
labelProjectId.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=200) # ???
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the minimum width for the grid *inside* the label. If you want to affect the column that the label is in, you must call `grid_columnconfigure` on its master.

Comment: So in my case, it looks like: `frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=200)`

Comment: @AlLelopath: yes.